# Filter by phrase possible?

Tags: serilog

Kinda new to serilog, but wanted to do something very simple, like:

```
            Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
                .MinimumLevel.Information()
                .Filter.ByExcluding("Could not find file")
                .WriteTo.File("SimplePlayerApartment-.log", rollingInterval: RollingInterval.Day, retainedFileCountLimit: 1)
                .CreateLogger();
```

I figured Filter.ByExcluding would allow me to not log lines with certain keywords/phrases in it. Instead, whatever documentation I can find, it seems to excluse based on namespace, classes, and all sorts of fancy things, whereas all I want is to filter out a simple string or 2.

Is there even any way of doing what I want? As the above code example throws a big fat runtime error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Filter.ByExcluding` is a predicate `Func<LogEvent, bool>`, so you need to give it a function that returns if the log event should be excluded or not...

```
Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
    .MinimumLevel.Information()
    .Filter.ByExcluding(e => e.MessageTemplate.Text.Contains("Could not find file")) // <#<#<#<
    .WriteTo.File("SimplePlayerApartment-.log", rollingInterval: RollingInterval.Day, retainedFileCountLimit: 1)
    .CreateLogger();

var fileName = "file.ext";

Log.Information("Hello");
Log.Information("Could not find file {fileName}", fileName); // Excluded from the log
Log.Information("Bye");
```

It's worth to mention that the example above applies the filter based on the message template which is (as it implies) the template before rendering, so `e.MessageTemplate.Text` would be `Could not find file {fileName}` instead of `Could not find file file.ext`.